# Flickr API Limit on Mathematica 11?

Tags: serviceexecute

I'm calling Flickr for pictures on Mathematica 11 with ServiceConnect, and I'm wondering if anyone knows if there is a limit on how many pictures Mathematica can call with Flickr.

Comment: If there is a limitation, isn't it going to be on Flickr's side?

Comment: I think I should migrate this to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/.  Does anyone disagree?